# Can we replace 2-fold cover by n rectangles with 1-fold cover by n rectangles?

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, discrete-geometry, covering

Suppose that $n$ rectangles cover every point of their union exactly twice (except for points on their boundaries).
Can we partition this union into at most $n$ rectangles?

I think it's pretty straightforward that we can assume that all rectangles are axis-parallel, so the problem can be interpreted as covering the fields of a matrix as well.
In fact my motivation comes from [this related question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/29277/on-the-notion-of-positive-rank/29306?noredirect=1#comment68862_29306).
I am also interested about what happens if instead of twice and once we ask some other multiplicities.